# Reshaping wide format positive/negative data into long format binary outcome

Tags: r, reshape

I have data that looks at pregnancy test results for heifers from a particular farm.

Eg.

```
Farm   Breed    Pregnant  Empty  Total  ADG
1      J        5         3      8      12
2      F        2         1      3      10
3      J        3         0      3      11
```

I would like the pregnant and Empty data to become a binary output and the other values just get repeated

Eg.

```
Farm   Breed  Pregnant  ADG
1      J      1         12
1      J      1         12
1      J      1         12
1      J      1         12
1      J      1         12
1      J      0         12
1      J      0         12
1      J      0         12
2      F      1         10
2      F      1         10
2      F      0         10
```

I have been trying to use the reshape code but are getting quite confused and was wondering if anyone may be able to help me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the "data.table" package in conjunction with `rep`. You want to repeat the values `1` and `0` by the numbers represented in the `Pregnant` and `Empty` columns, so you can easily create a `rep` statement for that. By default, the rows would "expand" by the `key`s you use to accommodate the new data.

Assuming you are starting with a `data.frame` named "mydf", try:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(mydf)[, list(Pregnant = rep(c(1, 0), c(Pregnant, Empty))), 
                    by = list(Farm, Breed, ADG)]
#     Farm Breed ADG Pregnant
#  1:    1     J  12        1
#  2:    1     J  12        1
#  3:    1     J  12        1
#  4:    1     J  12        1
#  5:    1     J  12        1
#  6:    1     J  12        0
#  7:    1     J  12        0
#  8:    1     J  12        0
#  9:    2     F  10        1
# 10:    2     F  10        1
# 11:    2     F  10        0
# 12:    3     J  11        1
# 13:    3     J  11        1
# 14:    3     J  11        1
```

The closest base R approach I can think of would be to first "expand" the relevant columns of the source dataset (easy, using `rep`) and then use `apply` to get the binary results for "Pregnant", like this:

```
cbind(mydf[rep(rownames(mydf), mydf$Total), 
           c("Farm", "Breed", "ADG")], 
      Pregnant = unlist(apply(mydf[c("Pregnant", "Empty")], 1, 
                              function(x) rep(c(1, 0), c(x[1], x[2])))))
#     Farm Breed ADG Pregnant
# 1      1     J  12        1
# 1.1    1     J  12        1
# 1.2    1     J  12        1
# 1.3    1     J  12        1
# 1.4    1     J  12        1
# 1.5    1     J  12        0
# 1.6    1     J  12        0
# 1.7    1     J  12        0
# 2      2     F  10        1
# 2.1    2     F  10        1
# 2.2    2     F  10        0
# 3      3     J  11        1
# 3.1    3     J  11        1
# 3.2    3     J  11        1
```

Comment: Oh this is much better than my `rep, rep, rep, rep, rep` method

Comment: @RichardScriven, I couldn't figure out a less `rep` based version than my base approach--I personally like the "data.table" one much more.

Comment: This code has worked really well and was easily applied to my data set easily. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Following is self-explanatory:

```
# repeat column values taking one row at a time and convert outcome list to a matrices:
> m1 = matrix(unlist(apply(ddf[,c(1,2,3,6)], 1, function(x) rep(c(x[c(1,2,4)],1), x[3]))), nrow=4)
> m2 = matrix(unlist(apply(ddf[,c(1,2,4,6)], 1, function(x) rep(c(x[c(1,2,4)],0), x[3]))), nrow=4)
> 
> 
> m1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "3"  "3"  
[2,] "J"  "J"  "J"  "J"  "J"  "F"  "F"  "J"  "J"  "J"  
[3,] "12" "12" "12" "12" "12" "10" "10" "11" "11" "11" 
[4,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  "1"  

> m2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "1"  "1"  "1"  "2" 
[2,] "J"  "J"  "J"  "F" 
[3,] "12" "12" "12" "10"
[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0" 

# combine, transpose and rename columns of matrices:
> mm = t(cbind(m1, m2))
> colnames(mm) = c('Farm','Breed','ADG','Preg_empty')
> mm
      Farm Breed ADG  Preg_empty
 [1,] "1"  "J"   "12" "1"       
 [2,] "1"  "J"   "12" "1"       
 [3,] "1"  "J"   "12" "1"       
 [4,] "1"  "J"   "12" "1"       
 [5,] "1"  "J"   "12" "1"       
 [6,] "2"  "F"   "10" "1"       
 [7,] "2"  "F"   "10" "1"       
 [8,] "3"  "J"   "11" "1"       
 [9,] "3"  "J"   "11" "1"       
[10,] "3"  "J"   "11" "1"       
[11,] "1"  "J"   "12" "0"       
[12,] "1"  "J"   "12" "0"       
[13,] "1"  "J"   "12" "0"       
[14,] "2"  "F"   "10" "0"
```

Comment: I don't find this to be "self explanatory" at all.

Comment: Some explanations added.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

 mydf %>%
   gather(Var, Val, Pregnant, Empty) %>% 
   mutate(N= row_number())%>%
   do(.[rep(.$N, .$Val),]) %>%
   select(Farm, Breed, ADG, Pregnant=Var) %>%
   mutate(Pregnant=c(1,0)[as.numeric(factor(Pregnant))]) %>%
   arrange(Farm, Breed)
```

gives the result

```
  #    Farm Breed ADG Pregnant
  #1     1     J  12        1
  #2     1     J  12        1
  #3     1     J  12        1
  #4     1     J  12        1
  #5     1     J  12        1
  #6     1     J  12        0
  #7     1     J  12        0
  #8     1     J  12        0
  #9     2     F  10        1
  #10    2     F  10        1
  #11    2     F  10        0
  #12    3     J  11        1
  #13    3     J  11        1
  #14    3     J  11        1
```

#### data

```
 mydf <- structure(list(Farm = 1:3, Breed = c("J", "F", "J"), Pregnant = c(5L, 
 2L, 3L), Empty = c(3L, 1L, 0L), Total = c(8L, 3L, 3L), ADG = c(12L, 
 10L, 11L)), .Names = c("Farm", "Breed", "Pregnant", "Empty", 
 "Total", "ADG"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score -6):

try `melt`

```
require(reshape2)
newdata<-melt(data[c(1:3,6)],id=c("Farm","Breed","Pregnant"))
```

Comment: always put some explanation to the answer you posted, so that others can get it easily.

Comment: What's `melt`?  Is that in a package?  Is the OP supposed to know where to find it?

Comment: When solution is there to your question, just put in a little effort to search it out yourself. Spoon-fed is not a good learning way.

Comment: chee.work.stuff: Was that comment addressed to @RichardScriven? If you review his questions, you would see that he's actually trying to dig into the language much more than others might be willing to . I don't find your comment appropriate, and your answer doesn't seem to do anything special except drop a few columns and transpose a few others--definitely not what the OP was asking for.